# Проблема считывания из бинарного файла.

Tags: c++

Есть такая иерархия классов:

```
class A 
{ 
public: 
    A(){} 
    A(int N): n(N){} 
    virtual ~A(){} 

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const A &operand) 
    { 
        out << operand.n << endl; 
        return out; 
    } 

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, A &operand) 
    { 
        in >> operand.n; 
        return in; 
    } 
protected: 
    int n; 
}; 

class B: virtual public A 
{ 
public: 
    B(): A(){} 
    B(int N, char C): A(N), c(C){} 
    ~B(){} 

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const B &operand) 
    { 
        out << operand.n << " " << operand.c << endl; 
        return out; 
    } 

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, B &operand) 
    { 
        in >> operand.n; 
        in >> operand.c; 
        return in; 
    } 
protected: 
    char c; 
}; 

class C: virtual public A 
{ 
public: 
    C(): A(){} 
    C(int N, double D) : A(N), d(D){} 
    ~C(){} 

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const C& operand) 
    { 
        out << operand.n << " " << operand.d << endl; 
        return out; 
    } 

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, C& operand) 
    { 
        in >> operand.n; 
        in >> operand.d; 
        return in; 
    } 

protected: 
    double d; 
}; 

class D : public B, public C 
{ 
public: 
    D(): A(), B(), C(){} 
    D (int n, char c, double d, char* Str): A(n), C(n, d), B(n, c) {strcpy(str, Str);} 
    ~D(){} 

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const D& operand) 
    { 
        out << operand.n << " " << operand.c << " " << operand.d << " " << operand.str << endl; 
        return out; 
    } 

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, D& operand) 
    { 
        in >> operand.n; 
        in >> operand.c; 
        in >> operand.d; 
        in >> operand.str; 
        return in; 
    } 
protected: 
    char str[20];  
};
```

В программе создаю объект object класса D, записываю его в бинарный файл. Далее вывожу его и убеждаюсь, что все работает. Выхожу из этой программки. Далее запускаю ее заново (бинарный файл, созданный при прошлом запуске этой же программы, еще живой :) ), считываю его в объект того же класса и при попытке считать этот объект получаю принудительное завершение программы.

Считываю и записываю в файл как обычно:

```
ofstream file("test.dat", ios :: binary | ios :: out); 
file.write((char*)&object, sizeof object); 
file.close(); 

ifstream file("test.dat", ios :: binary | ios :: in); 
file.read((char*)&object, sizeof object); 
file.close();
```

---

Примечательно, что еще в редких случаях может работать при первом перезапуске, а потом при следующих опять "выбрасывать". Еще у нескольких людей в группе такая проблема. У них тоже ромбовидное наследование и при подобных действиях возникает эта проблема.
Кстати, кинул исходник другу, который скомпилировал его. И у друга, согласно его словам, все работает. Он скинул мне свой exe-шник. История с ним повторяется, но в консоли появляется:

[image]

---

Компилятор Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что Вы хотите сделать, называется сериализация. Дело это не такое простое. В С++ нет стандартных средств для ее реализации (в отличии от Java и C#). Есть библиотека [Boost.serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). А так -можно просто сохранять в определенной последовательности требуемые переменные и далее их считывать и последовательно заполнять ими переменные другого объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Вот зачем было определять все эти операторы ввода-вывода, что бы потом просто так взять и записать данные через ссылку? Так как Ваши классы не являются pod типами, то писать их с помощью `file.write((char*)&object, sizeof object);` нельзя. Не pod типы не размещаются в памяти одним куском и могут иметь указатели на другие части. Поэтому если восстановить с файла после перезапуска, указатели будут указывать на произвольные места в памяти.
Но у так как у Вас уже есть операторы записи в поток, почему нельзя писать так

```
ofstream file("test.dat", ios :: binary | ios :: out); 
file << object; 
file.close();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Но при Вашем варианте на выходе я работаю не с бинарным файлом, а с текстовым, хоть и открытым в бинарном режиме, содержимое которого я спокойно читаю в блокноте (открыв бинарный файл, я бы увидел "кракозябры" различные). А по заданию мне нужно записывать и работать с бинарным файлом.
Просто нам преподы твердят, что файл открытый в бинарном режиме, но запись в который производится не функциями fwrite, cin.write, а обычным стандартными, нельзя считать бинарным. Так что извините, если я бред несу.)

Comment: Спасибо, что указали направление куда копать, т.к. я еще не знаю, в чем отличие POD и не-POD типов.

Comment: Только, что скомпилирован с помощью gcс, так там все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Любой текстовый файл является бинарным, обратное не верно.
Поэтому, существуют бинарные файлы, которые открываются в блокноте без "иероглифов".