# Сериализация

Tags: c++, сериализация

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане. 
Меня интересует всякая информация о сериализации в C++, да и вообще о ней в целом. Все началось с проблемы, описанной в [моем прошлом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93594/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0).

Конечно, понимаю, что наглею, т.к. там мне указали куда "копать". Но в учебниках я пока ничего похожего не нашел: возможно, плохо искал. Видел статьи на английском, но, надеюсь только пока, не особо в нем силен, по крайней мере со стороны технического перевода.

Главное для меня - полностью разобраться в причине проблемы, описанной в прошлом вопросе.
[KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim) мне там суть причины описал. Но **почему так происходит?** С чего это пошло? И почему в популярных книгах Дейтела и Шилдта я этого не встретил (возможно, я это пропустил либо не дочитывал до этого места...)?

Заранее очень благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я уже писал, что сериализация не входит в стандарт, поэтому в обычных учебниках Вы о ней и не прочтете. Поэтому для пользования ею нужно либо самому что-то реализовывать, либо пользоваться сторонними библиотеками, например, уже упомянутым Boost.Serialization.

А вообще, встает вопрос: зачем оно Вам? Вообще сериализация в С++ - дело довольно непростое и без крайней нужды лучше к ней не прибегать.

Comment: Спасибо, что всегда отвечаете.
Мне хотя разобраться для чего она нужна и как "это все дело" происходит.
Просто хочу раз и навсегда в этом вопросе разобраться, чтобы больше не попадать в подобные ситуации, когда не могу считывать бинарники в определенные объекты. 
Цитата в прошлом вопросе: "Не pod типы не размещаются в памяти одним куском и могут иметь указатели на другие части. Поэтому если восстановить с файла после перезапуска, указатели будут указывать на произвольные места в памяти." Она полностью верна? И где наиболее точно указаны границы между POD и не-POD типами.
Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: А гугль на что? Я вот с первой попытки накопал кучу источников. К примеру

http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=150319

Comment: О сериализации в С++ можно взглянуть здесь

http://wiki.shelek.ru/index.php/C%2B%2B_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85